# Java Spring Webflux WebClient - send http request using HTTP2

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding how to send HTTP2 requests using Webflux WebClient please.

One of our third party API did an upgrade, and they now support HTTP2.

Hence, I believe on my side, as a client, it is worth it to leverage this upgrade.

However, currently, I believe I am sending only HTTP1. To confirm, I saw the access log on the third party side, and it seems the requests are indeed HTTP1.

I have a WebClient bean, and using the bean to send requests.

```
WebClient.create().mutate().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(true).secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(getSslContext())))).build()

public Mono<ThirdPartyResponse> sendAnHTTP2RequestToThirdParty(ThirdPartyRequest request, Map<String, String> headers) {
        return webClient.mutate()
                .baseUrl(configuration.getThirdPartyUrl())
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri(ROUTE_ThirdParty)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setAll(headers))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ThirdPartyResponse.class);
    }
```

What are the configuration, or the code that I am missing please?

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify what HTTP/2 features you're wanting to take advantage of?

Comment: I believe there are many, but just to say a few, the new the better support for JWT, the per notification feedback can be interesting. Overall, just want to get started on this HTTP2 migration, however, for some reason unknown to me, all the requests I sent was still HTTP1. I even tried with a curl, while the curl command could yield HTTP2 requests, the web client seems to still send HTTP1 requests

Comment: well you have posted way too little information to answer the question, it's dependent on what server you have, what java version you are running etc. Here you can read about what springs documentation has to say about it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/HTTP-2-support

Comment: I mean, I am not asking if Spring supports it, it is written in the docs it does. My question os more like: Spring is supposed to support it. I am using Spring. Why are my requests still sent out as HTTP1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from Spring Team:

Reactor Netty provides two types of SslContext configuration:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/tcp/SslProvider.SslContextSpec.html

You can provide either SslContext or SslContextBuilder.

n your use case you provide SslContext for the HttpClient and thus we do not touch it. However there is no configuration for HTTP/2 support in that SslContext and in this case the client and the server will try to negotiate to use HTTP/1.1 protocol.

Solution:

Either extend SslContext with a configuration that supports HTTP/2
Or provide SslContextBuild and Reactor Netty will be able to apply some default HTTP/2 configuration

Verified and this is now rocking for me